# Designing "Income Statement" with crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, accounting

I am designing an Income Statement for a windows financial application. I want to create a report(Income Statement) like this:

[image]

Everything go right **until** I add last line (Total Net Income : ... ) and the shown report turn will be like:

[image]

In other words when I try to add the last line to my report, content of `Income Table`(Revenues) will repeat three times(as `Outgo Table`(Expenses) count).

**NOTE :** This is the formula of `Total Net Income`'s "Display String":

`ToText(Abs(Sum ({Income.bedehkar}) - Sum ({Outgo.bedehkar})))`

Comment: In crystal reports design where are you adding these fileds.. In which sections of the design.

Comment: @Siva subreport is placed in the `footer a` section of main report. and total net income is placed in the `footer b` section. Why?

Comment: In sub repot where are you placed the fields? your data is repeating.. this happens when there is duplicate data is coming to report which is repeating sections.. so check where the fields are placed and check the linking of tables and see the there is no duplicate data.